# when then default state in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update one column with relative to another one.
the problem is that i do not need to update all the values but only some.

for example:
lets say I have a table named "test" and to cols: dataset and createdAt.

I want to update the dataset to 1 if the CreatedAT is '2011-06-01' and to 2 if the CreatedAt is '2011-08-08' 
I do not want to make any changes to other cases .

I have tried this peace of code:

```
update test 
set dataset = (CASE 
 WHEN   DATE(createdAt) = '2011-06-01' 
                        THEN 1
                      WHEN   DATE(createdAt) = '2011-08-08' 
                        THEN 2
                    END);
```

the prolen is that all the other cases were the date is not one of those , the dataset get NULL instead of keeping its data.

Can any one please help?

Comment: @JaimeDrq There's no join required here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

One is to use a `WHERE` clause so you only process the rows that need to be changed:

```
UPDATE test
SET dataset = CASE DATE(createdAt)
        WHEN '2011-06-01' THEN 1
        WHEN '2011-08-08' THEN 2
    END
WHERE DATE(createdAt) IN ('2011-06-01', '2011-08-08');
```

The other is to assign the old value in the `ELSE` case.

```
UPDATE test
SET dataset = CASE DATE(createdAt)
        WHEN '2011-06-01' THEN 1
        WHEN '2011-08-08' THEN 2
        ELSE dataset
    END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a WHERE statement:

```
update test 
set dataset = CASE 
  WHEN DATE(createdAt) = '2011-06-01' THEN 1
  WHEN DATE(createdAt) = '2011-08-08' THEN 2
END
WHERE DATE(createdAt) IN ('2011-06-01', '2011-08-08')
```

This way all the rows that don't need to be updated will not be affected. 
Also there is no need for an `ELSE...` part in the `CASE` statement as it would cause useless updates and maybe unwanted side effects and would arise performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
UPDATE test 
SET dataset =
    CASE 
        WHEN DATE(createdAt) = '2011-06-01' THEN 1
        WHEN DATE(createdAt) = '2011-08-08' THEN 2
        ELSE dataset 
     END
```

Comment: It should be `else dataset`

Comment: Right, Updated.